# How to replace string in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, pug

I'm trying to replace the default pug tag to october cms partial. I can't replace string in file. Pug file for example:

```
include frames/header.pug

img(src="img/123123.jpg", alt="")
img(src="img/1.jpg", alt="")
include frames/footer.pug
```

How I can replace:

```
include frames/footer.pug
```

on

```
{% partial 'frames/footer' %}
```

but the name of included file (footer in this example) can't be known.

I have a function for this, but it's not working.

```
.pipe(replace(/include frames\/{1}\/.pug/g, "{% partial 'frames/$1' %}"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

//  .pipe(replace(/frames/(.*).pug/g, "{% partial 'frames/$1' %}"))

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var  replace  =  require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('replace', function () {

  return gulp.src(['app.pug'])
     .pipe(replace(/frames\/(.*)\.pug/g, "{% partial 'frames/$1' %}"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

app.pug (before):

```
include frames/header.pug

img(src="img/123123.jpg", alt="")
img(src="img/1.jpg", alt="")

include frames/footer.pug
```

dist/app.pug (after):

```
include {% partial 'frames/header' %}

img(src="img/123123.jpg", alt="")
img(src="img/1.jpg", alt="")

include {% partial 'frames/footer' %}
```

Comment: ye in parts its work, but it does not insert finded word on replace, result is ({% partial 'frames/$1' %}) ((( Mayne u know how to change to "{% partial 'frames/footer.pug' %}", where footer pug is unkown...

Comment: What do you mean by footer.pug is unknown?  I assumed it was coming from include frames/footer.pug - and header.pug would be pulled from include frames/header.pug .  Aren't you staring with include frames/footer.pug?  And you want to change that to {% partial 'frames/footer' %} ?  What is your starting point and what do want after gulp-replace?

Comment: Ye i need replace "include frames/footer.pug" to  "{% partial 'frames/footer' %}", Your code replaces the string on {% partial 'frames/$1' %}

Comment: I added the test pug file and gulpfile.js that I used to test the replace regexp - it appears to be working fine.  I must not be understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank u so much. Now  everything  work correctly. That was my plugin (gulp-string-replace) im changing him on your gulp-replace, and now all working fine! You are Awesome!